# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel, when android recreates Activity and Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, recreate, viewmodelproviders

Case is of `Activity-Fragment` Recreate : I am creating `ViewModel` from activity `context` at `activity` level and trying to access the initialised `ViewModel` at `Fragment` level, using `ViewModelProvider`.of().

Below code works in happy case; but when activity is recreated (changes system language or permission), same code don't work, and fragment is not able to access the activity created viewModel.

ViewModel is parameterised and has only one primary constructor and initialised using ViewModelProvider.Factory

## ViewModel Structure

```
class MessageViewModel(var message: MutableLiveData<String>): ViewModel() { ... }
```

## ViewModel Initialisation at Activity

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, MessageVMFactory())
            .get(MessageViewModel::class.java)
```

## Accessing ViewModel at Fragment

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity)
            .get(MessageViewModel::class.java)
```

## Error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.krp.android.viewmodeldemo/com.krp.android.viewmodeldemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.krp.android.viewmodeldemo.utility.MessageViewModel

Answer (score 3):

If you have initialised the ViewModel via Factory, you must access it via Factory, regardless of any context. Seems ViewModel issue when system recreates activity or fragment.

**It works fine at Fragment when**

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity, MessageVMFactory())
                .get(MessageViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks for the sharing , we often stuck on this.